# passing user-data as a string to aws cli ec2 run-instance command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, user-data

I am trying to provide bash command for bootstrapping my ec2 instance during creation time in the following way

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-0000025f7c02a13b2 --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --user-data '#!/bin/bash\nyum install git -y'
```

I can spin up the ec2 but I cannot get the bash script to work. In the logs I see the following

```
/bin/bash\nyum: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

which makes me feel like the string is formatted wrong.

Comment: I tested on my terminal and the command executed without any errors.

Comment: you mean the install git command or spinning up the ec2 command. I can spin up the ec2 just fine but the bash script I provide using user-data does not get executed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a `$` in front of your user data string.

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-0000025f7c02a13b2 --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --user-data $'#!/bin/bash\nyum install git -y'
```

Comment: Worked!! Thank you! I spent so much time on it. Should've asked the question a lot earlier

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to load a long script, it would be better to load the script from a file like this:

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-abcd1234 --count 1 --instance-type m3.medium \
--key-name my-key-pair --subnet-id subnet-abcd1234 --security-group-ids sg-abcd1234 \
--user-data file://my_script.txt
```

and you file should be like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
yum update -y
service httpd start
chkconfig httpd on
```

See more details about loading data from a file while working with `aws cli` from [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html)

Comment: thanks! where is the file being loaded from. Can it be an s3 path

Comment: most welcome:) the file would be in the same location where you run this command, if you need to load from s3, I guess you will have to download it first from s3 to the current location and then use it `--user-data file://$(aws s3 cp s3://bucket/folder/file.txt)`. I did not try this before, but you can give it a go :)